# Text ugly wraps the star icon on developer survey page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, survey-2019

Look for this weird aligned text on [developer survey 2019 page](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019):

> [image: star]

Comment: it's because the background-position is `center left`

Comment: Thanks, fix going up in a few minutes!